# What domain should I whitelist to authenticate Alexa on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit, whitelist, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm trying to install Alexa on my Raspberry Pi Zero W using  [AlexaPI](https://github.com/alexa-pi/AlexaPi) , but when I try to authenticate at http://localhost:5050 error "400 Bad Request" shows up. It says: "The redirect URL you provided has not been whitelisted for your application." and in the "Request Details" section it gives this :

`client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.1428c05ba6ed4b8790faf98601f743d1&scope=alexa%3Aall&scope_data=%7B%22alexa%3Aall%22%3A+%7B%22productID%22%3A+%22A3DS27MW3BUU5H%22%2C+%22productInstanceAttributes%22%3A+%7B%22deviceSerialNumber%22%3A+%22e0a9599b09b88cab74600a17f4c568ae3171a65c18835ae3e1df5b395b60c4da%22%7D%7D%7D&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5050%2Fcode`

But what should I whitelist? http://localhost:5050 is already whitelisted.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, but in general this is possible very easy. I'm hosting a lot of services on my PIs.

Answer (score 0):

The whitelisted redirect url should be `http://localhost:5050/code`, not `http://localhost:5050`

Comment: well, something is wrong. Maybe client_id? Note that the urls must be exact. So for example http and https are different. It might be best to add all possible permutations.